# DataSource.InsertParameters.Add("UserId", UserGUID.ToString()); Object reference not set to an instance of an object error

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I have been following the tutorial to create additional fields in the Create User Wizard here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020103243/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/070506-1.aspx#postadlink

I am getting an error of Object reference not set to an instance of an object on my line DataSource.InsertParameters.Add("UserId", UserGUID.ToString());

My ASP Code is this:

```
    <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" oncreateduser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser">
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center" colspan="2">
                            Sign Up for Your New Account
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                                ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password"
                                ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <asp:Label ID="ConfirmPasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmPasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword"
                                ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." ToolTip="Confirm Password is required."
                                ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordCompare" runat="server" ControlToCompare="Password"
                                ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The Password and Confirmation Password must match."
                                ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1"></asp:CompareValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email">E-mail:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
                                ErrorMessage="E-mail is required." ToolTip="E-mail is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <asp:Label ID="ManagerFirstNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ManagerFirstName">First Name:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ManagerFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ManagerFirstNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ManagerFirstName"
                                ErrorMessage="First Name is required." ToolTip="First Name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <asp:Label ID="ManagerSurnameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ManagerSurname">Surname:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ManagerSurname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ManagerSurnamRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ManagerSurname"
                                ErrorMessage="Surname is required." ToolTip="Surname is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <asp:Label ID="TeamNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="TeamName">Team Name:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TeamName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="TeamNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TeamName"
                                ErrorMessage="Team Name is required." ToolTip="Team Name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <asp:Label ID="TeamStadiumLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="TeamStadium">Team Stadium Name:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TeamStadium" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="TeamStadiumRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TeamStadium"
                                ErrorMessage="Team Stadium Name is required." ToolTip="Team Stadium Name is required."
                                ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <asp:Label ID="RecieveReminderLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RecieveReminder">Recieve Reminder Email:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="RecieveReminder" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <asp:Label ID="RecieveSummaryLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RecieveSummary">Recieve Summary Email:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="RecieveSummary" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center" colspan="2" style="color: Red;">
                            <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center" colspan="2" style="color: Red;">
                            <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
        <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server" />
    </WizardSteps>
</asp:CreateUserWizard>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="InsertAdditionalUserDetails" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RaiseFantasyLeagueConnectionString %>"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [UserDetails] ([UserId], [ManagerFirstName], [ManagerSurname], [TeamName], [TeamStadium], [RecieveReminder], [RecieveSummary]) VALUES (@UserId, @ManagerFirstName, @ManagerSurname, @TeamName, @TeamStadium, @RecieveReminder, @RecieveSummary)" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="ManagerFirstName" Type="String" ControlID="ManagerFirstName" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="ManagerSurname" Type="String" ControlID="ManagerSurname" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="TeamName" Type="String" ControlID="TeamName" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="TeamStadium" Type="String" ControlID="TeamStadium" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name= "RecieveReminder" Type="Boolean" ControlID="RecieveReminder" PropertyName="Checked" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name= "RecieveSummary" Type="Boolean" ControlID="RecieveSummary" PropertyName="Checked" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and C# code is this

```
        protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox UserNameTextBox = (TextBox)CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("UserName");
        SqlDataSource DataSource = (SqlDataSource)CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("InsertAdditionalUserDetails");

        MembershipUser User = Membership.GetUser(UserNameTextBox.Text);

        if (User != null)
        {
            object UserGUID = User.ProviderUserKey;
            DataSource.InsertParameters.Add("UserId", UserGUID.ToString());
            DataSource.Insert();
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Check UserGUID object

Comment: I'm quite new to asp.net and c#. What am I looking for?

Comment: Your trying to get String value from "UserGUID.ToString()", may be in your case "UserGUID is Null".

Comment: I think that is the case, it seems the user is not created yet to retrieve the ID. But i'm using the CreatedUser Event so shouldn't they already be there?

Answer (score 0):

Your "DataSource" or "UserGUID" is NULL.

Comment: It seems the user is not created yet. so I can't retrieve the ID. But i'm using the CreatedUser Event so shouldn't they already be created?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146830/membership-getuser-provideruserkey-always-returns-null 
may be this link will helpful to you.

Comment: you can also check "UserNameTextBox.Text" value passing into Membership.GetUser method may be having space on it. try to pass UserNameTextBox.Text.Trim()

Answer (score 0):

this error you are getting because you are trying to convert object to string. Try this it might help you

instead of object use var
**var user**

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem

```
protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MembershipUser User = Membership.GetUser(CreateUserWizard1.UserName);
    object userGUID = User.ProviderUserKey;
    TextBox firstname = (TextBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("FirstName");
    TextBox lastname = (TextBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("LastName");
    TextBox companyname = (TextBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("CompanyName");
    TextBox address1 = (TextBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Address1");
    TextBox address2 = (TextBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Address2");
    TextBox city = (TextBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("City");
    DropDownList state = (DropDownList)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("State");
    TextBox zip = (TextBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Zip");
    TextBox phone_number = (TextBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Phone");
    TextBox email_address = (TextBox)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Email");


    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("userid", userGUID.ToString());
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("firstname", firstname.Text);
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("lastname", lastname.Text);
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("companyname", companyname.Text);
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("address1", address1.Text);
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("address2", address2.Text);
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("city", city.Text);
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("state", state.SelectedValue);
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("zip", zip.Text);
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("phone_number", phone_number.Text);
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("email_address", email_address.Text);
    SqlDataSource1.Insert();
}
```