# Get UserId (int) in new MVC4 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, membership

New MVC4 application created UserProfile table :

UserId(int) | UserName(nvarchar)

In controller :

```
  string currentUser = User.Identity.Name;  // returns UserName

  var mu1 = Membership.GetUser(); // returns null

  var mu2 = Membership.GetUser(currentUser); // returns null as well
```

I read a lot of threads and they all talk about getting Guid, which I don't even have in user and membership tables.

Is there a way to get the UserId (int) of currently logged in User ?

Comment: Why do you need the id?

Comment: @andri, to store ad FK in another table.

Comment: Why not use the username as FK? The username is unique, isn't it?

Comment: @andri you should be careful when using a user name in this manner because you may have the situation where a user deletes or changes their name, then another user registers with the same username... there could be trouble!

Answer (score 12):

Make sure you add `[InitializeSimpleMembership]` to the top of your controller so that it initializes the simple membership via the file `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs` in the `Filters` directory.

Then you can access the user id in several different ways:

```
int mu1 = (int)WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
int mu2 = (int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
```

Comment: My InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute is located in Filters\InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute so I added `using RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Filters;` on the top of my controller but my int `mu1 = (int)WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;` gives me `The name 'Websecurity' does not exist in the current context. So I used `using WebMatrix.WebData;` will this still work?

Answer (score 3):

You can get UserId as int with

```
WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
```

**Additional Information:** You should add `[InitializeSimpleMembership]` on top of controller class if you use another  controller than AccountController.

Answer (score 0):

`mu1` and `mu2` will contain an instance of [`MembershipUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx) if the user has successfully authenticated. `MembershipUser` has a `ProviderUserKey` property of type `object` that will contain the identifier for a user.

`Membership.GetUser()` requires a MembershipProvider to be hooked up for the application and for the user to be authenticated; since you are seeing `null` returned, this would suggest that one of the aforementioned conditions is not met.

Answer (score 0):

You can get UserId

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
 {
  var membership = (SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider; 
  int idUser = membership.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
 }
```