# Get id of the logged in user in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using `asp.net SimpleMembership`. I'm trying to show the id of the logged-in user in a `ViewBag`. For some reason I'm getting NULL for `ProvidedUserKey()`. Here is my code,

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(ClientReg user)
    {            
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.username, false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
    }

[Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string userId = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();    //Null error in this line
        ViewBag.UserId = userId;
        return View();
    }
```

**View**

```
<div class="container">
    @ViewBag.UserId
</div>
```

How can I get the id of the logged-in user?

Comment: how are you authenticating the user? did you also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146830/membership-getuser-provideruserkey-always-returns-null

Comment: yes, I did checked this post before. But I can't understand it's explanation.

Comment: ensure that the user is actually authenticated....I don't really see any authentication code except for setting a cookie value which is not really truly authenticating the user

Comment: I've provided a short version of my full code. In full, I've ensured that user is 100% authenticated & I can only fetch his username, but I also want to fetch his other infos from db. Any idea how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Use this class instead of Membership:

```
WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
```

Simple Membership inherits the WebSecurity instance and is more reliable way to get the data for the user.

Answer (score -1):

```
object id = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey
```